# Automapper not mapping a computed property

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a simple interface like:

```
interface IEntity
{
    int EntityID { get; }
}
```

and a number of classes implementing using a computed property for the `EntityID`, like so:

```
class Person : IEntity
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public int EntityID => PersonID;
}
```

I'm trying to map to another class with the same property, like the one below, using Automapper:

```
class Result
{
    public int EntityID { get; }
}
```

I can't get it to map the property though. The test below fails because the `EntityID` in the result is always `0`, even when I explicitly set the `ForMember()` mapping, like below:

```
using AutoMapper;
using Xunit;

public class UnitTest1
{       
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<IEntity, Result>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.EntityID, i => i.MapFrom(src => src.EntityID)))
            .CreateMapper();

        var result = mapper.Map<Result>(new Person() { PersonID = 5 });
        Assert.Equal(5, result.EntityID);
    }
}
```

There has got to be some obvious solution I'm missing here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am pretty sure ti will work without mapper ;)

Comment: Where is the setter? :)

Comment: @Lucian Bargaoanu . My God, I'm an idiot! Adding the setter fixed it. I knew I had to be doing something silly. Thanks, if you add that comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple properties, AM needs a setter to work, as with the manual approach.